# How to format and convert varchar to datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to cast a varchar to a datetime so i can find out max and min values. The varchar that i have is like this format:  'Mon, 24 May 2010 21:24:39 +0000' and I need to cast to: '2010-05-24 21:24:39'. I am using mysql server. Need help.

Comment: What frontend are you using

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use MySQL to do this, as it is only primarily designed for database management.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Myvarchar, '%a, %d %b %Y %T') FROM table1
```

This will turn it into a format in the column with which you can then run less than and greater than, min and max queries. You can run queries on it leaving it as a string but it will of course have less performance than a new column with the proper datetime type in it rather than a varchar. You won't notice a performance problem though if there are not too many rows.

So you might end up running this:

```
SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Myvarchar, '%a, %d %b %Y %T')) FROM table1
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date